# How to I use CoreNFC with an ApplicationDelegate for Qt?

Tags: ios, objective-c, qt, nfc

I am not an Objective-C person. But I'm trying to get CoreNFC to work with Qt. So far I can bein up the session UI, Scan a tag but I get a stack error.

Here's what I did.

1. Take care of app entitlements and such.
2. For my QIOSApplication Delegate, it was

   @interface QIOSApplicationDelegate : UIResponder

changed to:

```
@interface QIOSApplicationDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate>
```

3. Add to the delegate:

   @property (strong, nonatomic) NFCNDEFReaderSession *nfcSession;

Four. Just as a test, in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, add:

```
if (![NFCNDEFReaderSession readingAvailable]) {
    qDebug() << "NFC not available";
} else {
    qDebug() << "NFC available";
    _nfcSession = [[NFCNDEFReaderSession alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil invalidateAfterFirstRead:NO];
    [_nfcSession beginSession];
}
```

Five. Add the following functions to the app delegate:

```
- (void)readerSession:(NFCNDEFReaderSession *)session didDetectNDEFs:( NSArray<NFCNDEFMessage *> *)messages {
    qDebug() << "NFCNDEFReaderSession didDetectNDEFs" << messages;
    NSLog(@"NFCNDEFReaderSession didDetectNDEFs: %@",messages);
    for (NFCNDEFMessage *message in messages) {
        qDebug() << message;
        for (NFCNDEFPayload *payload in message.records) {
            qDebug() << payload;
        }
    }
}

- (void)readerSession:(NFCNDEFReaderSession *)session 
didInvalidateWithError:( NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@",error);
}
```

6. Launch App, present tag to phone (along the top).The phone makes the indication that it read a tag though with a sound and vibrate.

Seven. I get the "Stack Error" *after* seperating the phone and the tag.  The error function never gets called.

```
2018-10-04 17:36:09.291926-0400 testnfc[532:51484] [CoreNFC] 00000002 838b2f80 -[NFCNDEFReaderSession _connectTag:error:]:418 Error Domain=NFCError Code=100 "Stack Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Stack Error, NSUnderlyingError=0x2818a2970 {Error Domain=nfcd Code=15 "Stack Error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Stack Error}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

After receive data, I just `invalidate` the session.